# Is there a proper way in python to restrict the shape of a numpy array with pattern matching?

Tags: python, numpy

Let `x` be a numpy array of shape (400, 2)

I want the following to be true:

```
if x.shape == (*, 2):
    ...
```

if `x` would have the shape (300, 1) the condition should evaluate to false.
But apparently you neither can use `*` nor `_`.
Is there any way in python to achieve such a pattern matching?

Comment: why isnt `if x.shape[1] == 2:` enough?

Comment: in fact one can create an abstract pattern matching for shapes by employing such conditions into a generic function

Comment: @NikosM. didn't think of that, thanks ^^' I am python beginner .. but you probably would do `x.shape[1] == 2 and x.ndim == 2:` then?

Comment: yeap checking dimensions would indeed make it robust

Answer (score 2):

You can simply access the tuple returned by `x.shape` and check for the dimensions of `x`:

```
if x.shape[1] == 2 and x.ndim == 2:
    ...
```

would do the job.

Comment: better reverse the tests, so if `x.ndim == 1` for example the whole code wont break apart by `Exception`. So write: `if x.ndim == 2 and x.shape[1] == 2:`